# add multiple list in good map marker

Tags: php, google-maps, yii2, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I am developing a web application for Real Estate and I want to show a map on listing page with multiple marker showing multiple Homes/properties in same area. I am doing this in `yii2/php`. I need suggestion how I can do it? I already have added maps for every home/property,

Answer (score 3):

For similar purposes, I use [2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library) (in my case it's not houses but some sort of 'facilities').

**Update**: I'm giving you concrete code examples for each step. First of all, you have to understand that to situate elements in the map you have to create `LatLang` objects. You create one simplty specifying its latitude and longitude coordinates (Google maps gives you those in the proper format), i.e.: `$coord = new LatLng(['lat' => 49.403916, 'lng' => 17.036116])`.

The first step is creating the map, and for that you have to provide where it has to be centered. You can specify also the level of zoom, and some other things you can check in the module's docs:

```
$map = new Map([
    'center' => $coord,
    'zoom' => 4,
    'width' => '100%'
]);
```

Once you hace the maps, you can start adding things. In my case, i add facilityes (`Facilty` model). I store its coordinates (Latitude, Longitude), name, address, etc. Then, I loop over an array of `Facility`ies (`foreach $f in $facilities`) and for each one:

1. Create a `LatLang` object with its coordinates: `$coord = new LatLng(['lat' => $f->lat, 'lng' => $f->lng]);`
2. Create a new `Marker`:

   ```
   $marker = new Marker([
                   'position' => $coord,
                   'title' => $lab['name_lab'],
                   'animation' => 'google.maps.Animation.DROP',
                   'visible'=>'true'
               ]);
   ```
3. Create an `InfoWindow` with the Facility's info (name, address) and attach it to the `Marker` (you can write html in its content): `$marker->attachInfoWindow(new InfoWindow(['content' => $f->address]))`
4. Add the marker to the `Map`: `$map->addOverlay($marker);`

Finally, after the loop, we display the map:

```
echo $map->display();
```

A complete example:

```
$coord = new LatLng(['lat' => 49.403916, 'lng' => 17.036116]);
$map = new Map([
    'center' => $coord,
    'zoom' => 4,
    'width' => '100%'
]);

foreach ($facilities as $f) {
    $coord = new LatLng(['lat' => $f->lat, 'lng' => $f->lng]);
    $marker = new Marker([
                'position' => $coord,
                'title' => $lab['name_lab'],
                'animation' => 'google.maps.Animation.DROP',
                'visible'=>'true'
            ]);
     $marker->attachInfoWindow(new InfoWindow(['content' => $f->address]));
     $map->addOverlay($marker);
}    

echo $map->display();
```

There are a lots of customization options, but this should be enoguh to get you started. Please, check the module's docs as well as Google map's.

Comment: Thank you for your answe Mr.gmc. I tried to user 2amigos but I could not be able to understand it's working.

Comment: Thank you very much but can you provide more descriptive info?

Comment: Mr.gmc can you please help me in 4th step?? I did above steps and now i am thinking how to create map either inside of foreach or outside of it.

Comment: You have to create the map outside the loop, and steps 1 to 4 should be inside. Step 4 is where you add the marker to the map. There should be one final step outside the loop (after) that actually displays the map, I'm adding it right now to the solution

Comment: but where to initiate map? inside or outside?

Comment: `<?php foreach ($locations as $locs): ?>

          <?php 
           $coord = new LatLng(['lat' => $locs->lat, 'lng' => $locs->lan]);
          

           $marker->attachInfoWindow(new InfoWindow(['content' => $locs->formatted_address]));
           $map->addOverlay($marker);
            
           ?>
         <?php endforeach ?>

         <?php echo $map->display(); ?>` This is my code but where to initillize the $map?